# Zend controller router route regex mapping variable twice? earlier working fine later not

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, routes

I have a following route configure in routes.ini

```
routes.frontnoncms.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.frontnoncms.route = "/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?(newsletter|contactus|accessability|search)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.frontnoncms.defaults.module = frontManagement
routes.frontnoncms.defaults.controller = Front
routes.frontnoncms.map.locale = 1
routes.frontnoncms.map.action = 2
routes.frontnoncms.map.page = 2
routes.frontcms.map.subpage = 3
routes.frontcms.map.num = 4
```

if you notice parameter two is assigned twice.

**routes.frontnoncms.map.action = 2**

**routes.frontnoncms.map.page = 2**

results are

```
array(4) { ["locale"]=> string(2) "en" ["action"]=> string(9) "contactus" ["module"]=> string(15) "frontManagement" ["controller"]=> string(5) "Front" }
```

There is a action element in array but there is no Page element.

So I swap their positions and move the page line above the action line. something like this

```
routes.frontnoncms.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.frontnoncms.route = "/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?(newsletter|contactus|accessability|search)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.frontnoncms.defaults.module = frontManagement
routes.frontnoncms.defaults.controller = Front
routes.frontnoncms.map.locale = 1
routes.frontnoncms.map.page = 2
routes.frontnoncms.map.action = 2
routes.frontcms.map.subpage = 3
routes.frontcms.map.num = 4
```

Now result are somehting like this.

```
array(4) { ["locale"]=> string(2) "en" ["page"]=> string(9) "contactus" ["module"]=> string(15) "frontManagement" ["controller"]=> string(5) "Front" }
```

Now there is Page element in array but this time Action element is gone.

Does this mean, I can only assign a parameter once? I won't assign it twice?
because later is not working.

Comment: Can I ask you why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I was expecting this question :)  I am just curious :) why it is not working as in htaccess it works.

Comment: curiosity kills the cat!! Maybe this works ?? really not sure though `routes.frontnoncms.map.page = routes.frontnoncms.map.action`

Comment: hate when people ask why :) its part of my implementation. and nice try :) but I already tried this. it did not work.  any other guess ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it like this, because in the Zend_Framework it's coded like this

```
// params of the function
$values = array(1 => 'en_GB', 2 => 'index', 3 => 'awesome-subpage');

foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->_map)) {
        $index = $this->_map[$key];
    } elseif (false === ($index = array_search($key, $this->_map))) {
        $index = $key;
    }
    $return[$index] = $values[$key];
}
```

It itterates through the keys (1,2,3,4) just check that the key has a mapping name (eg. page) and continue so if you have two mapping name for one key it doesn't work.

If you want to achieve this you have to either extends the `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` and extends the function `_getMappedValues` (but quite ugly) or in your controller asign the value action to page in your `preDispatch` (but quite ugly) or change your application design.

If you want more info you should look at `_getMappedValues` function on the `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`